# find -exec exit 1 \; Doesn't work neither does find -exec sh -c exit 1 \;

Tags: shell, find

Using Enterprise Linux 5/6, Bash 4.x I want this type of logic:

```
# IF temp file exists, exit because we are restarting already     
find /tmp/restarting_server -mmin -10 -exec exit 1

lsof -i TCP:1234 || declare Server_is_down=TRUE
    if ! [ -z $Server_is_down ]; then restart_server
    fi
# Restart Server Function
restart_server() {
    touch /tmp/restarting_server 
    service server restart
    rm -f /tmp/restarting_server 
}
```

The problem is find's -exec doesn't like builtins it seems.  I know I can do an if then statement to check for the file and exit there, but I want to know how to do this in a find -exec (or I'd settle for a good xargs solution).

Comment: What is supposed to exit? The `find` command or the script itself?

Comment: @terdon The script should exit with 1.

Comment: For more on `find`'s exit status, scroll down to the near the end of `man find`: "find  exits  with  status  0  if  all files are processed successfully,greater than 0 if errors occur." Not finding a match is not considered an error because the command actually ran correctly, it simply had no results. You'll get an error if you try searching in a directory that does not exist for example: `find /hahagd/ ; echo $?`.

Comment: @terdon I understand that is how Find's exit status behaves.  I intend to cause the script, which is running every 5 minutes as a cron job, and has the find as the first line, to exit before running the next line(s) if the find command finds this tempfile.  The tempfile existing is proof that the restart function is currently executing, so there is no need for the script to run this time.

Comment: You can't exit the parent script from within find. `find -exec` is running in a separate subshell and has no knowledge of the script. The way to exit is what l0b0 and devnull have suggested.

Comment: Im pretty sure you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while [ -f /tmp/restarting_server ] ; do {
    [ $((i=i+1)) -ge 10 ] && exit 1
    sleep 1 
} ; done
```

You dont need `find` if you know already the exact filename, pathname, and conditions under which a file should be acceptably found.

So the other problem - exiting your script from your `-exec` statement - is maybe not the problem you consider it to be. `find` doesn't build in an option for `kill`ing its parent shell because the shell already provides it.

```
find … -exec sh -c kill\ $$ \;
```

Consider also that you can use this construct for signalling based on existing paths even if you're not certain before hand where they'll be:

```
trap 'stuff to do' USR1    
… #later… 
find … -exec sh -c kill\ -USR1\ $$ \;
```

And this opens a lot of other options to you as well:

```
find … -exec sh -c exec…
```

***EDIT:***

I've just thought of other options involving `parameter expansion` to make your shell exit without `find`'s `-exec` at all that could be used in other ways:

```
hold_file="$(find . -name file)"
${hold_file:+false} : || exit 1
```

or

```
N= ; hold_file="$(find . -name file)"
${hold_file:+${N:?lock file remains, exiting...}}
```

Both of these will only cause an exit if the variable to which you assign `find`'s `stdout` is neither `null` or unset. And of course, should you desire to fail based on an empty find, you can do the same with `:-` instead of `:+` and omitting the `$N`ull value variable entirely.

Or just to alter `find`'s exit status:

```
$(find . -name file -exec echo false \; ) : || exit 1
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I thought of the find … -exec sh -c kill\ $$ (see it in my comments above, however I chose to put $$ into a different variable earlier on).  I guess I assumed there was some feature of find that I wasn't aware of which was useful for this.  Perhaps I am too set on using the wrong tool for the job here, I just thought it made a nice one liner.

Comment: Bah. 'Wrong tool for the job' is probably a mantra you should abandon. Do what works.

Comment: Oh, and you dont need to use a different $var because the shell evaluates the expansions before running the command - so when `find` receives that argument string it will already be evaluated. I dont know if `find` properly evaluates `$$`, but if so one escape like `\$$` would kill the `find` process and `'\$$'` would kill its child `sh` process.

Comment: You can use `-exec kill $$ \;`, no need to invoke an intermediate shell for this. You'll need the final `;` however.

Comment: Really? `find` will run a shell builtin or you have a literal `kill` in `$PATH`? If the latter - that's not always the case.

Comment: @mikeserv no it isn't. if you don't use the right tool for the job, you're creating brittle code that can't be easily modified because you had to jump through hoops to get the original to work. plus, why wouldn't you use the right tool? refusing to do so without an external motivation is just stupid.

Comment: No what isn't? And how do you know what the right or wrong tool is except that it does or doesn't work? Tools evolve based on use - if you tailor a tool to your purpose, it grows better for your having done so.

Comment: @Gilles - thanks for the `\;` correction - I wrote it on my tablet and didn't test it first. But I wonder, does your `find` really run the `kill` builtin? If so that's pretty cool.

Comment: @mikeserv No, `find` runs the external `kill` command. A builtin is some string that has a particular meaning to a shell, so to run a builtin, you need to run a shell.

Comment: I get that - it's a POSIX guaranteed `special-builtin` so it's not necessarily available as a single executable binary. That's what I figured, but I wasn't sure. Thanks again for the heads-up, though, @Gilles.

Answer (score 4):

You could check if it returned a result:

```
[ -z "$(find /tmp/restarting_server -prune -mmin -10)" ] || exit 1
```

Comment: Not bad.  exit status of find doesn't work $? it's 0 whether it finds it or not, but this is a nice idea.

Answer (score 2):

`find` is a program of its own. The argument to `-exec` is another command. When a command like `find … -exec foo {} \;` is executed, the shell has `find` as a subprocess, and each instance of `foo` is a subprocess of `find`. The command `exit` exists only as a shell builtin, not as an independent command; an `exit` program would be impossible since it would have to make its parent process exit.

The solution to your immediate problem is thus to make `find` report whether it found a file or not, and make the shell exit if there was a match. You can't use the return status of `find`, because it considers the absence of any match to be a success reason. Instead, test the output.

```
if [ -n "$(find /tmp/restarting_server -mmin -10)" ]; then exit; fi
```

Here, the file should be a regular file if it exists at all. However, in general, the file could be a directory, in which case `find` would traverse it. So tell `find` to stop when it finds a match.

```
if [ -n "$(find /tmp/restarting_server -mmin -10 -prune)" ]; then exit; fi
```

---

However, the resulting script is not reliable. You are not implementing a lock correctly. If two instances of the script start at almost the same time, it's possible to have, for example:

1. Script 1 starts, sees no `restarting_server` file, and proceeds merrily.
2. Script 2 starts, sees no `restarting_server` file, and proceeds merrily.
3. Script 1 sees that the server is down and decides to restart it.
4. Script 2 sees that the server is down and decides to restart it.
5. Script 1 creates `/tmp/restarting_server`.
6. Script 2 updates the timestamp on `/tmp/restarting_server`.
7. Script 1 calls `service server restart`.
8. Script 2 calls `service server restart`.
9. Script 1 removes `/tmp/restarting_server`.
10. Script 2 calls `rm -f /tmp/restarting_server` which does nothing.

Call [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) to implement proper locking.

```
(
  lsof -i TCP:1234 >/dev/null ||
  service server restart
) 3>/var/lock/maybe_restarting_server
```

You don't need a timeout to invalidate the lock across reboots, since the locking is held in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
if [ "$(find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name restarting_server -mmin -10)" = '/tmp/restarting_server' ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

This works even if you're using `set -o errexit` (which you should).

Comment: This is wrong I believe.  Find will return 0 whether it finds the item or not.  Your solution will always exit 1

Comment: @GreggLeventhal you're right. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks.  This solution isn't bad, but I was hoping to learn how to exit an enclosing script from the -exec argument of a find within that script.  Something like script_pid=$$;find /tmp/tempfile -exec kill $script_pid \;  But better.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal It's not clear to me [why you would want to do that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). This way you can trivially add for example logging and cleanup code without making the code a mess.

Comment: Haha, I know that page (i've even been on his IRC ).  Perhaps find simply isn't meant to behave that way since as Terdon points out, exec is run in a subshell which in itself removes it from the context of the script that called it.  I guess I was just wondering it there is a find based solution that I was missing, but I guess not.  Occam's razor.